# How to decide when i will use Bridge and Decorator pattern in my project and actual conceptual difference both of them

Tags: c#

Hey i am working as software developer and starting to understand design pattern, please give me the concept about the bridge and decorator pattern. Already I have gone through the previous post of the related topic but i am not cleared about that please help me!!.

Answer (score 0):

I have found Christopher Okhravi a YouTube VLogger to have posted some interesting videos about various design patterns, including Bridge & Decorator.

He does so in a quite entertaining (considering the subject) and presents it in a fairly easy to understand manner.

Decorator Pattern:
https://youtu.be/GCraGHx6gso

Bridge Pattern:
https://youtu.be/F1YQ7YRjttI

You can also check out this website:
https://www.oodesign.com/

Answer (score 0):

```
First of all we need to know what is the meaning of Bridge and Decorator pattern??
Bridge: The GOF definition of Bridge pattern is "Decouple an abstraction from its implementation so that the two can vary independently". and this pattern is fall under structural design pattern, why structural because you are changing the structure of our application.
Let's analysis this : Let you implement a business Logic 

Class Business
{
public void Operation()
{
//you business logic here
}
}

Class Client 
{
Business b=new Business();
b.Operation();
}

please consider in the above "Business" class, is for your application structure that you have implemented and with this structure your client is happy.

Now say after One year your client is requesting you to change their business operation structure as well as previous implemented operational structure remain same for some clients. Now what you will do?
Lets see

Class Business
{
public void Operation()
{
//you business logic here
}

public void NewOperation()
{
//you New business logic here
}
}

Class Client 
{
Business b=new Business();
b.NewOperation();
}


Now assume how many changes you need to done for new operation.
Here bridge pattern help a lot;
interface IOperation
{
void operation();
}

public class ConcreteOPeration:Ioperation
{
void operation
{
//you code
}
}

public class NewConcreteOPeration:Ioperation
{
void operation
{
//you new code code
}
}

Public interface OperationBridege
{
void callOperation();
}

Public Class ConcreteBridge:OperationBridege
{
private Ioperation _ioperation;

public ConcreteBridge(Ioperation _operation )
{
this._ioperation=_operation;
}

void callOperation()
{
this._ioperation.operation();
}

}

class client
{
//Ioperation oprtn =New ConcreteOPeration();//NewConcreteOPeration
//if you change to new operation need know change just 
the new concreteOperation class
Ioperation oprtn =New NewConcreteOPeration();

OperationBridege bridege =new ConcreteBridge(oprtn);
bridege.callOperation();
}

Any where you using this operation nothing impacted in your application for structural changes for this pattern fall under structural design pattern.

Now we discuss about Decorator pattern.
Decorator: The GoF definition is "Attach additional responsibilities to an object dynamically. Decorators provide a flexible alternative to subclassing for extending functionality."
Lets analysis this if you want to add some additional facilities dynamically in your previously implemented  class then GOF suggested at this situation we will must use decorator design pattern.
Let see an example

public interface IComponent
    {
        void Operation();
    }

    public class ConcreteComponent:IComponent
    {
        public void Operation()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This is the main functionality!!!");
        }
    }


    public class Decoretor:IComponent
    {
        protected IComponent component;
        public void SetComponent(IComponent _component)
        {
            this.component = _component;
        }


        public virtual void Operation()
        {
            component.Operation();  
        }
    }


    public class ConcreteDecoratorA : Decoretor
    {

        public override void Operation()
        {
            base.Operation();
        }
    }

    public class ConcreteDecoratorB : Decoretor
    {

        public override void Operation()
        {
            base.Operation();
            Show();
        }

        public void Show()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Additional resposiblity attached");
        }
    }


class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            IComponent c = ComponentObjCreator.ComponentCreator();

            //Decoretor d = new ConcreteDecoratorA();//In this class have basic //functionalities
            Decoretor d = new ConcreteDecoratorB();//in this class has some additional 
            functionalities
            d.SetComponent(c);
            d.Operation();


}
}

Actually here we decorated our application structure with some new functionalities
and we are implemented in the "ConcreteDecoratorB" class that's why we are called this decorator business pattern.it's also fall under structural design pattern.
```

Comment: Thank you @Debabrata Saha, this is great article for those who are actually doesn't know design pattern, I have some doubt in my mine but all most i have cleared  concept and boost up my understanding !!

Answer (score 0):

Both of them are in the **structural patterns** category in the Gof.

we use the Bridge Pattern when we need to have some separated logic that when we need to use each of them.  for example, you have software to send multiple types of notification to users like SMS, Email and sets. here we use **the Bridge Pattern**.

On the other hand when we need to implement a system to add some specific behavior to object we use a Decorator pattern. For example, you decide to make an IceCream Machine with multiple choosable things like Honey, Bread, nuts and ... here we use **the Decorator pattern** (Also known as Wrapper).

There is some useful information on below links

[Decorator Design Pattern](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/decorator)

[Bridge Deign Pattern](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/bridge)